# Copy an entire row to another sheet given an instance in the row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a big sheet worth of data and want to copy and paste all rows containing `"HVT"` to another sheet. I am new to VBA and I think the code I have searches the entire cell instead of the contents of the cell. For example if the cell said only `"HVT"` it would work, but the cells have multiple strings in them. An example of something that could be in a cell would be something like `"mechanical system damper HVT purchased"`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value = "HVT" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel if statements accept wildcards, so you just need to know if you want to match the whole word "HVT" or not:

Match whole word:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value Like "* HVT *" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value Like "HVT *" Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value Like "* HVT" Then
```

Or match any instance of HVT ("xHVTx" returns `true`):

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11).Value Like "*HVT*" Then
```

Will work

Answer (score 0):

Below code has been updated:

```
Sub transferHVT()

Dim mySH As Worksheet
Set mySH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim sSH As Worksheet
Set sSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sh2_Row As Integer
sh2_Row = 1
For a = 2 To mySH.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(mySH.Cells(a, 11).Value, "HVT") <> 0 Then
        'Loop through all the column
        For b = 1 To mySH.Cells(a, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            sSH.Cells(sh2_Row, b).Value = mySH.Cells(a, b).Value
        Next b
        sh2_Row = sh2_Row + 1
    End If
Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: that got copied the specific cells HVT was in, but I was looking to copy the entire row

Comment: try the updated code that loop through all the column of the copied row